# How Can I use Filehandling to save and access login in java

Tags: java, user-interface, file-handling, file-writing, filehandle

How can I use File handling as database, like how can I store and access my username and password? I'm not allowed to use SQL database.

I am using jframe GUI - I created my username and pass bar on Jframe and one more thing my previous username is replacing with my new username. How can I save my username and pass on next line eachtime? Please guide me or give me a program in which you used GUI and file handling at same time..Thank you!

I have tried every thing but nothing is going well

Code of filehandling which I tried:

```
private void RbuttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                        

    String username=Cuser.getText();
    String password=Cpass.getName();

    FileWriter filewriter;
    try{
        filewriter=new FileWriter("Record.txt");
        try (BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(filewriter)) {
            bufferedWriter.write(username+" "+password);
        }
    } catch (IOException ex){
        System.out.println("Error! ");

    }

}
```

when I run my program it shows username but do not show password it shows null instead of pass in my notepad file

Comment: Can you give more details on CPass and CUser?

Comment: I created Cpass and cuser through jframe

Comment: How did you create them? You need to include the code that reads from the file, not just the code that prints the results

Comment: i did not created that yet

Comment: I want you guys to give me code to read file so that i cann login to my account

Answer (score 0):

Utilizing a Database is by far the better way to go here but if that possibility doesn't exist then for small use-cases like this I think it is just better to load the file login data into an ArrayList or List Interface and do whatever needs to be done against the list. When the time is right, just save the list and overwrite the data file.

This eliminates the possible constant use of file access which can be troublesome and slow.

Below is a runnable with some simple methods that demonstrates this scheme. It starts by doing a single read of the data file and places the data (UserName|Password) of all registered Users into a List. The data file is always automatically created if it doesn't already exist. This list is then accessed for for all matters related to the Login portion of the application such as adding new User Records, deleting User Records, determining is a User already exists within the file, determining if a User Name and Password combination is correct, and displaying a list of registers Users within the file. Writes to the file are only done when a new User is Auto-Added, or a User is deleted (there is no mechanism provided to access User Deletion but the method is made available).

Here is he runnable code. The code is well commented:

```
/* Java 7+ Required....

   Displays a custom JOPtionPane Login Dialog and allows for a User to enter
   a User Name and Password. The supplied User Name and Password is compared 
   to a text file (LoginRecords.txt) which is automatically created to store 
   the login data upon successful input (if it doesn't already exist).
*/

package filedblogin;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JPasswordField;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;


public class FileDBLogin {

    // Required Class member variables
    private List<String> fileData;                      // The list to hold file data
    private final String ls = System.lineSeparator();   // OS line separator used in dialogs
    private final String dbFile = "LoginRecords.txt";   // Path and name of data file
    Boolean accessGranted = false;                      // Flag to indicate whether access is granted or not
    JFrame iFRAME = new JFrame();                       // Dummy JFrame component for JOptionPane's

    // Startup main() method...
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | 
                                    javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(FileDBLogin.class
                .getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);

        }
        //</editor-fold>

        // Do this to eliminate the need for statics.
        new FileDBLogin().startApp(args);
    }

    // Application start up method (called from main())...
    private void startApp(String[] args) {
        // Set up a default base component for JOptionPane dialogs
        iFRAME.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        iFRAME.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        iFRAME.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        // Read in file data. display the number of records in console
        System.out.println("There have been " + readInData() + " Users reserved in memory." + ls +
                "Remove this Console Print when testing is completed.");
        // Start the login process by calling the userLogin() method...
        accessGranted = userLogin();

        /* Indicate whether or not access is granted. Also give
           the option to view all registered Users in file.  */
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(iFRAME, "Access is granted to this application:  " + 
                accessGranted + ls + "Do you want to see a List of Registered Users?", "Finally....", 
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        iFRAME.dispose();   // Dispose of the dummy JFrame
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            showUsers(2); // Show list of Users in columns of 2;
        }
        System.out.println("Application Ended!"); // Indicate application ended.
    }

    private boolean userLogin() {
        boolean success = false;    // Flag used to indicate whether or not login was successful.
        // Use a Custom Login Dialog (see the loginDialog() method JavaDoc)
        String userNameAndPassword = loginDialog("Application Login", 
                "<html>Please supply your <font color=blue>User Name</font> and <font color=blue>Password</font><br>"
                        + "in order to access this application:</html>", "User Name:", "Password:", 1);
        String username = userNameAndPassword.split(";")[0]; // Parse User Name from Login Dialog results
        // Is User Name valid?
        if (username.equals("")) {
            // No...not valid...
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, "Invalid or no User Name supplied!",
                    "Invalid User Name", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            iFRAME.dispose();   // Dispose of the dummy JFrame
            return success;     // success is still false
        }

        String password = userNameAndPassword.split(";")[1];  // Parse Password from Login Dialog results
        // Is Password valid?
        if (password.equals("")) {
            // No...not valid...
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, "Invalid or no User Password supplied!",
                    "Invalid User Password", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            iFRAME.dispose();   // Dispose of the dummy JFrame
            return success;     // success is still false
        }

        // If the supplied User Name is not in file records...
        if (!isUserNameInFile(username)) {
            // Do what you like here for a New User or use this...
            if (addUserRegistration(username, password)) {
                // Add User to file.
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, "Welcome " + username + "! You have been "
                        + "auto-registered for access." + ls + "Please remember your User Name and "
                        + "Password.", "Auto-Registered", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
                iFRAME.dispose();
                success = true;  // Grant Access
            }
        }
        // If supplied User Name and Password is in records...
        else if (isUserRegistered(username, password) > -1) {
            // Inform of success.
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, "Login Successful! Welcome " + username,
                    "Login", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            iFRAME.dispose();
            success = true;     // Grant Access
        }
        // If User Name is in records but password is wrong...
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, "Login Unsuccessful! Invalid User Name or Password!",
                    "Login Failure", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            iFRAME.dispose();
        }
        return success; // success is still false
    }

    // Show Registerd Users List
    private void showUsers(int columns) {
        /* Using HTML within the Message for athe JOptionPane 
           Message Dialog. Places a Bold Title and a borderless
           table of names. If you want a border then change the
           border='0' to border='1' in the first line below.
        */
        String msgString = "<html><b>Current Registered Users:</b><br><br><table "
                         + "border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'><tr>";
        int counter = 0;    // Used for keeping track of desired table columns
        // Iterate through file records in List and create HTML Table
        for (int i = 0; i < fileData.size(); i++) {
            counter++;
            String strg = fileData.get(i).split("\\|")[0].trim();
            strg = "<td align='left' width='160' height='15'>" + strg + "</td>";
            msgString += strg;
            if (counter == columns) {
                msgString += "</tr>";
                counter = 0;
            }
        }
        msgString += (!msgString.endsWith("</tr>") ? "</tr>" : "") + "</table></html>";
        // Display the list of registered Users in file
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, msgString, "Registered Users",
                JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        iFRAME.dispose();
    }

    // Add New User
    private boolean addUserRegistration(String username, String password) {
        boolean success = false;
        // Is User Name already registered?
        if (isUserRegistered(username, password) > -1) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, "The Supplied User name is already registered!",
                    "Already Registered", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
            iFRAME.dispose();
        }
        else {
            // Add User to records
            fileData.add(username + "|" + password);
            if (writeDataToFile()) { 
                success = true;
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    // Delete a Registered User...
    private void deleteUserRegistration(String username, String password) {
        int result = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(iFRAME, "Are you sure you want to delete '"
                + username + "'?" + ls + "There is no Undo for this action!", "Delete User",
                JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
        iFRAME.dispose();
        if (result == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
            for (int i = 0; i < fileData.size(); i++) {
                if (fileData.get(i).split("\\|")[0].trim().equals(username) && fileData.get(i).split("\\|")[1].trim().equals(password)) {
                    fileData.remove(i);
                    break;
                }
            }
            writeDataToFile();
        }
    }

    // Is the supplied User Name and Password already registered?
    private int isUserRegistered(String userName, String password) {
        int nameIndexVal = -1;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileData.size(); i++) {
            String name = fileData.get(i).split("\\|")[0].trim();
            String pass = fileData.get(i).split("\\|")[1].trim();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(userName) && pass.equals(password)) {
                nameIndexVal = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        return nameIndexVal;
    }

    // Is the supplied User name already used in records
    private boolean isUserNameInFile(String username) {
        boolean success = false;
        for (int i = 0; i < fileData.size(); i++) {
            String name = fileData.get(i).split("\\|")[0].trim();
            if (name.equalsIgnoreCase(username)) {
                success = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        return success;
    }

    // Read file data into List<String>
    private int readInData() {
        fileData = Collections.emptyList();
        try {
            fileData = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(dbFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            // If the File doesn't exist then create it.
            if (ex.toString().contains("NoSuchFileException")) {
                fileData = new ArrayList<>();
                PrintWriter pw = null;
                try {
                    pw = new PrintWriter(dbFile);
                }
                catch (FileNotFoundException ex1) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, "Cant not create the '" + dbFile
                            + "' File!" + ls + ex, "File Creation Error",
                            JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                    iFRAME.dispose();
                }
                if (pw != null) {
                    pw.close();
                }
            }
        }
        return fileData.size();
    }

    // Write List<String> to file by way of overwrite
    private boolean writeDataToFile() {
        boolean success = true;
        try {
            Files.write(Paths.get(dbFile), fileData, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(iFRAME, "Error writing data to File!" + ls + ex.toString(),
                    "File Write Error", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
            iFRAME.dispose(); 
            success = false;
        }
        return success;
    }

    // Custom Login Dialog
    /**
     * Displays a Custom input dialog in the form of a Login Dialog Window.<br><br>
     * 
     * @param dialogTitle (String) The dialog window Title.<br>
     * 
     * @param dialogMessage (String) The message string for the dialog window. HTML tags 
     * can be used within the supplied string however the tags {@code "<html>"} or 
     * {@code "</html>"} will be stripped from the string if they exist. These tags 
     * are automatically applied to the supplied string.<br>
     * 
     * @param nameCaption (String) The desired caption to be used for the User Name 
     * Text Field label.<br>
     * 
     * @param passwordCaption (String) The desired caption to be used for the Password 
     * Text Field label.<br>
     * 
     * @param buttons (Integer) Supply 0 to display only the OK button within the 
     * Input Dialog or supply 1 to display the OK and CANCEL buttons within the
     * Input Dialog. Default is 0.<br>
     * 
     * @return (Semicolon (;) Delimited String) The entered User Name and Password 
     * are returned separated by a semicolon (;), for example: "My Name;12345". If
     * the dialog was closed or CANCEL was selected then a Null String ("") is 
     * returned.
     */
    private String loginDialog(String dialogTitle, String dialogMessage, String nameCaption, String passwordCaption, int buttons) {
        int btns = 0;
        if (buttons == 1) {
            btns = JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION;
        }
        if (nameCaption.equals("")) {
            nameCaption = "User Name:";
        }
        if (passwordCaption.equals("")) {
            nameCaption = "Password:";
        }
        // Create panels and apply components
        BorderLayout layout = new BorderLayout();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(layout);
        dialogMessage = dialogMessage.replaceAll("(?i)\\<html\\>|(?i)\\</html\\>", "");
        JLabel label = new JLabel("<html>" + dialogMessage + "<br><br><br></html>");
        panel.add(label, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        JPanel p = new JPanel(new BorderLayout(5, 5));
        JPanel labels = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        labels.add(new JLabel(nameCaption, SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        labels.add(new JLabel(passwordCaption, SwingConstants.RIGHT));
        p.add(labels, BorderLayout.WEST);
        JPanel controls = new JPanel(new GridLayout(0, 1, 2, 2));
        JTextField userName = new JTextField();
        controls.add(userName);
        JPasswordField password = new JPasswordField();
        controls.add(password);
        p.add(controls, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        p.add(new JLabel(" "), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(p);

        // Get User Name and Password input from User...
        int res = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(iFRAME, panel, dialogTitle, btns);
        iFRAME.dispose();
        // Was the OK button select in the custom Input Dialog
        if (res == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION && !userName.getText().equals("")
                && !new String(password.getPassword()).equals("")) {
            String passWrd = new String(password.getPassword()); 
            return userName.getText() + ";" + passWrd;
        }
        return ""; // return nothing is the dialog was closed or Cancel was selected.
    }
}
```